# Getting nulls after replacing Dataframe columns with other DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes; `telecom` and `num_telecom`. `num_telecom` contains some *numerical values*, that I would like to replace the in `telecom` dataframe using this data:

```
telecom.head()

    tenure  PhoneService PaperlessBilling MonthlyCharges TotalCharges   Churn
0        1             0                1          29.85        29.85       0
1       34             1                0          56.95      1889.50       0
2        2             1                1          53.85       108.15       1
3       45             0                0          42.30      1840.75       0
4        2             1                1          70.70       151.65       1

telecom.shape
(7032, 6)

telecom.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7032 entries, 0 to 7031
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   tenure                                 7032 non-null   int64  
 1   PhoneService                           7032 non-null   int64  
 2   PaperlessBilling                       7032 non-null   int64  
 3   MonthlyCharges                         7032 non-null   float64
 4   TotalCharges                           7032 non-null   float64
 5   Churn                                  7032 non-null   int64>
```

Similarly we have num_telecom having following columns (scaled using standard scaler)

```
num_telecom.head()
tenure  MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges
0   -1.280248   -1.161694   -0.994194
1   0.064303    -0.260878   -0.173740
2   -1.239504   -0.363923   -0.959649
3   0.512486    -0.747850   -0.195248
4   -1.239504   0.196178    -0.940457

num_telecom.shape
(7032, 3)

num_telecom.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7032 entries, 0 to 7031
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   tenure          7032 non-null   float64
 1   MonthlyCharges  7032 non-null   float64
 2   TotalCharges    7032 non-null   float64
```

replacing column values for `telecom` with `num_telecom`:

```
numVars=['tenure','MonthlyCharges','TotalCharges']
telecom[numVars] = num_telecom[numVars]
```

Now, from where we are getting null values in `telecom` data frame as there is no **not-null** *values* in `num_telecom`?

```
telecom.info()

#   Column                                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                                 --------------  -----  
 0   tenure                                 7021 non-null   float64
 1   PhoneService                           7032 non-null   int64  
 2   PaperlessBilling                       7032 non-null   int64  
 3   MonthlyCharges                         7021 non-null   float64
 4   TotalCharges                           7021 non-null   float64
 5   Churn                                  7032 non-null   int64
```

Comment: Can you try `telecom[numVars] = num_telecom[numVars].values`?

Comment: @Chris .. Hi Chris! you've solved my problem. thank you. But why is this happening?

Comment: Try `telecom.index.eq(num_telecom.index).all()`? I suspect two datas have different indices and thus pandas fills the missing indices with `nan` instead of plainly taking the values.

Comment: @Chris.. getting this error for the same..  'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'eq'.. got your point. trying the same with isin()

Comment: @ Chris.. Yes you are right. There are missing indices . ```print(telecom.index.isin(num_telecom.index).all())``` giving False